# WordPress configuration DB_Host

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, configuration, localhost

In my server I've IIS & SQL server, then i install xampp and change the port from 80 to 81 in httpd.conf in Apache/conf folder. Now i can access both server & mysql fine.

```
ServerName localhost:81
```

also, `Listen 81`

But when i started configuring WordPress, it cannot establish a connection with "localhost" as a Database Host. I've already tried to establish connection including port number in host name, but it did not work.

> Error establishing a database connection

Any Idea?

Comment: did you made changes in your wp-config.php ?

Comment: i was using the default installation wizard, like http://localhost:81/folder_name

Comment: Solved it, silly problem, the issue was with the privilege of the user.